# Installing GNU scientific library and linking to programme

Tags: linux, installation

I am trying to install a statistical program which requires GNU Scientific Library (GSL). I have successfully installed GSL through the `yum` command, but my statistical program gives an error when I try to run `make install`. I think there is a linking problem. How can I solve it?

```
$ sudo yum install gsl.x86_64
Installed:
  gsl.x86_64 0:1.15-3.fc16
Dependency Installed:
  atlas.x86_64 0:3.8.4-1.fc16
$ tar -xvzf prog.tgz
$ cd prog
$ make
$ gcc -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/     -c -o prog.o prog.c
In file included from prog.c:16:0:
prog.h:7:30: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [prog.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to me like you have installed the library binaries, but not the headers and other supplementary files needed for "development" (which includes simply compiling ready-made applications that make use of the library).

Look for packages with names like `gsl-dev`, `gsl-headers` and the likes. Those (-dev etc.) usually contain the files needed to compile software against the library in question. Install the appropriate package and try again.

Also, look for an INSTALL, BUILD (or similar) file in the source code tree. *Usually* there is a `configure` step which you are eliding in the set of commands you list in your post.

Answer (score 7):

on Centos 6.5 :

```
yum install gsl-devel
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Works on Amazon Linux AMIs as well.

Comment: And RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.6